# Rewriting img source URL from .htaccess

Tags: php, image, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a little problem. I have img with wrong source.

The source is :

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/mk/thumbnail.php?file=file-dtik.jpg&amp;size=article_medium" align="left" alt="image">
```

And the source need to be changed to

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/thumbnail.php?file=file-dtik.jpg&amp;size=article_medium" align="left" alt="image">
```

Without the MK folder after the website.
I need to change this via .htaccess ? What is the rewrite rule for this ?

**EDIT :**
Also another problem. THere is some .pdf links which are not linking correctly i need them also to re-link with .htaccess.

```
http://207.58.130.89/~tempuser/mk/files.php?force&file=documents/documents/file.pdf
```

This is the current link and i need redirect when someone click to :

```
www.mydomain.com/mk/files.php?force&file=documents/documents/file.pdf
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should always prefer to code such rewriting rules in the server configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. The reason is that such files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and really slow the server down.

*Rules example for the server configuration:*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/mk/thumbnail\.php$ /thumbnail.php [L,QSA]
```

There are only two exceptions to this rule:

- you do not have access to the server configuration
- your code needs to make dynamic changes to the set of rewriting rules

*Rules example for `.htaccess` style files:*

(note that you first have to enable usage of such files inside the server configuration)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^mk/thumbnail\.php$ thumbnail.php [L,QSA]
```

For this rule to work the .htaccess style file must be located inside the document root at top level, where the `mk` folder exists, physically or virtual.

---

Disclaimer: I did not test-run this, sorry if there is some typo...

In general you should *always* consult the excellent [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this stuff!

---

In case you have problems getting such rewriting rules to work, there are three basic places where to start debugging:

1. if you have access to the server log files, then that is where you should start: first you should see error entries when the rewritten request does not point to the expected location or otherwise fails
2. even more elegant is to use the builtin rewrite logging, if you have control about the server configuration. It allows to gain really detailed insight into what is (or is not) going on inside the rewriting engine. See the documentation ink I posted above for details.
3. you can specify a temporary and additional "external redirection flag" which allows you to see the url the request is written to in your browsers url bar. For this just replace the flags `[L,QSA]` b a `[L,QSA,R=301]` which results in the server sending an external redirection header on http level instead of performing a silent and internal rewriting. This often helps to understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason i use .htaccess is that the website is using vivo framework and iam here only to fix the problem. I have never used vivvo framework. This dont work. But when i try to remove the /mk/ folder from firefox firebug the image immidietely shows. Any extra help in here?

Comment: All fine, rewriting is a valid approach for such a task.

Comment: Yeah i know. The rewrite didnt pass.. Any other suggestion ?
When iam located on mywebsite.com/mk/ the image urls are with /mk/thumbnail?... and they are not showing. But when iam located on the index of my website mywebsite.com the image urls are like thumbnails?.... and they are showing

Comment: Well, in your question you wrote that the url is `...thumbnail.php?...`, whilst in your last comment, the `.php` is suddenly missing? Apart from that, I added hints about how to start debugging potential issues...

Comment: Thanks. The problem is fixed. See my EDIT on top(another problem) i tried with your solution again and no success. Your solution only fixed my first problem.

Comment: Considering your last comment and your `edit` in the question: obviously the rules I posted only rewrite requests to links holding the `thumbnail.php` anchor, they have to either be doubled and adapted for other request patterns, or you have to generalize them. However the structure of the requests makes me wonder if you are on the right track. This looks more like some already present rewriting rules (or similar configuration details like `Alias` rules) are out of sync and you are now trying to fight fire with fire instead of fixing the original issue.